# How to list the 3rd party softwares installed in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

Is there a way to list the 3rd party softwares installed in Centos?
I have tried using ***rpm -qa***  
but it contains the native packages also.
I am looking for something similar like Installed section in "Software Center in GUI mode" in CLI mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have CentOS install. So I will show it how I will do that on my Fedora:

```
$ rpm -qi rpm |grep Vendor
Vendor      : Fedora Project
```

This will get me who is vendor of rpm package. You may have there something like CentOS. Get that string. And then:

```
$ rpm -qa --qf '%{name} %{vendor}\n' | grep -v 'Fedora Project'
```

This will print all installed packages which are not from vendor "Fedora Project".

Comment: Excellent approach. I have used "rpm -qa --qf '%{name} %{vendor}\n' | egrep -v 'CentOS|none' | less". And this showed me exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot